# How to tell AndroidStudio to be less pedantic about native code

Tags: android-studio, suppress-warnings, clang-tidy

I am using [AndroidStudio](https://developer.android.com/studio) to build [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/) based applications with C and C++ code.

The IDE goes overboard with warnings, like the one below:

[image: clang-tidy warning]

How can I disable this and other gratuitous warnings from the IDE?
Is this done on a per-project base, or an IDE setting?
In any case, the deluge of warnings are not helping.

- Ubuntu LTS
- Android Studio 3.5
- Native code built via gradle/cmake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release notes of Android Studio state:

> Android Studio now includes support for static code analysis using
>   Clang-Tidy for projects that include native code. To enable support
>   for Clang-Tidy, update your NDK to r18 or higher. You can then enable
>   or re-enable the inspections by opening the Settings or Preferences
>   dialog and navigating to Editor > Inspections > C/C++ > General >
>   Clang-Tidy. When selecting this inspection in the Settings or
>   Preferences dialog, you can also see the list of Clang-Tidy checks
>   that are enabled and disabled under the Option section of the
>   right-most panel.

To disable the warnings just go to:

> Preferences->Editor->Inspections->C/C++->General->Clang-tidy

and uncheck Clang-tidy or edit the list of checks to disable those that annoy you.